# Websphere Network deployment datasource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, jndi

I have installed Websphere Network deployment server 7.0.0.0
I have configured a cluster on it.
I have configured a data source on it say ORA_DS this data source using "JAAS - J2C authentication data"
When i test the ORA_DS by clicking on "Test connection" button, the test connection is success.

The issue comes when i try to access this data source using my java code.

Here is my code to access data source and create a connection:

```
public class DSTester
{
    /**
     * Return the data source.
     * @return the data source
     */
    private DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        DataSource dataSource = null;

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:9811");

        // Retrieve datasource name
        String dataSourceName = "EPLA1";
        if (dataSource == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Context initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
                dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup(dataSourceName);
            }
            catch (NamingException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        DSTester dsTester = new DSTester();
        DataSource ds = dsTester.getDataSource();
        System.out.println(ds);
        System.out.println(ds.getConnection());
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
    com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@17e40be6
Exception in thread "P=792041:O=0:CT" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
DSRA0010E: SQL State = 72000, Error Code = 1,017
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:406)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOauth(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:799)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:368)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:275)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:139)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:88)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1212)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:2019)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1422)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSDefaultConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(WSDefaultConnectionManagerImpl.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:646)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:613)
    at com.test.DSTester.main(DSTester.java:70)
```

The code works fine if i replace

```
ds.getConnection()
```

with

```
ds.getConnection("ora_user", "ora_password")
```

**My issue is i need to get the connection without specifying login details for Oracle.**

Please help me on this issue.
Any clue will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it would work if you retrieved the datasource from an application running on the WAS.

Try creating a servlet.

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("EPLA1");
Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
```

As within a servlet it is running within WAS it should be fine, if the "Test Connection" works. Running it outside is probably a different context.

Comment: I tried accessing the data source from EJB and it did not work. So finally i decided to provide user name and password in getConnection() but still waiting for solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check all your configuration:
1) Is it application deplyed on cluster or into only one of cluster member? 
2) JAAS - J2C authentication data - what is the scope?

Sometimes you need restar all your WAS environment. It depends on resource configuration scope

I'd recomend to you add resource refences for better configuration options.
See[IBM Tech note](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21281096)